# Someone can use array of json in .net?

Tags: asp.net, arrays, json

I am trying to integrate my application with the mercadolibre API. I can list a new item without problem, but when I try to insert a picture array the integration is not working.
Error message:

```
{"message":"body.invalid_field_types","error":"[invalid property type: [pictures] expected List but was null value: [pictures:[[source:http://www.nichepursuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/buy-websites.jpg], [source:http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/639229/176602316/stock-vector-best-buy-rubber-stamp-red-icon-isolated-on-white-background-vector-illustration-176602316.jpg]]]]","status":400,"cause":[]}
```

When I try to use the second option below, Visual Studio show me an error of compilation.

I already tested a lot of kind of declaration but all failed.

**Tentative 1:**

```
IRestResponse r = m.Post("/items", ps, new
                {
                    title = _item.title,
                    category_id = _item.category_id,
                    price = _item.price,
                    currency_id = _item.currency_id,
                    available_quantity = _item.available_quantity,
                    buying_mode = _item.buying_mode,
                    listing_type_id = _item.listing_type_id,
                    condition = _item.condition,
                    description = _item.description,
                    warranty = _item.warranty,
                    pictures = new {pictures = new [] 
                    {
                        new {source = "http://www.nichepursuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/buy-websites.jpg"}, 
                        new {source = "http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/639229/176602316/stock-vector-best-buy-rubber-stamp-red-icon-isolated-on-white-background-vector-illustration-176602316.jpg"}
                    }}
                });
```

**Tentative 2:**

```
IRestResponse r = m.Post("/items", ps, new
            {
                title = _item.title,
                category_id = _item.category_id,
                price = _item.price,
                currency_id = _item.currency_id,
                available_quantity = _item.available_quantity,
                buying_mode = _item.buying_mode,
                listing_type_id = _item.listing_type_id,
                condition = _item.condition,
                description = _item.description,
                warranty = _item.warranty,
                pictures = [{"Source":"Value"},{"Source":Value2}]

            });
```

Comment: Describe "not working". Are you getting an error? How does it not accomplish what you want?

Comment: Hi mason. I already edit this topic. Thanks.

Comment: You said it throws a compilation error now, but you need to explain what the compilation error is.

Comment: On the first code block `pictures` is doubled: `pictures = new {pictures = new [] ...`. Try just `pictures = new [] ....`

Comment: Thank you. The soluction is below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# knows nothing about JSON arrays, fortunately, it has it's own.

**Your code:**

```
 pictures = new {pictures = new [] 
                {
                    new {source = "http://www.nichepursuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/buy-websites.jpg"}, 
                    new {source = "http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/639229/176602316/stock-vector-best-buy-rubber-stamp-red-icon-isolated-on-white-background-vector-illustration-176602316.jpg"}
                }}
```

This is actually not an array, but anonymous object.
**Try rewriting it:**

```
pictures = new[] 
{
    new { source = "http://www.nichepursuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/buy-websites.jpg" },
    new { source = "http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/639229/176602316/stock-vector-best-buy-rubber-stamp-red-icon-isolated-on-white-background-vector-illustration-176602316.jpg"}
}
```

or even just array of strings:

```
pictures = new string[] 
{
    "http://www.nichepursuits.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/buy-websites.jpg",
    "http://thumb9.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/639229/176602316/stock-vector-best-buy-rubber-stamp-red-icon-isolated-on-white-background-vector-illustration-176602316.jpg"
}
```

Second option:
`pictures = [{"Source":"Value"},{"Source":Value2}]` is not a valid line, you aren't allowed to write this in C#.